# Jquery On and Off Button

Tags: jquery, button

I can't for the life of me get this button to work correctly! Essentially I want it to add the cities layer, and remove the cities layer based on the click.

```
<button id="mainCities" class="classname">  <span class="ui-button-text">Main Cities</span></button>

 $("#mainCities").click(function(){
  $("span", this).text(function(i, text){
    return text === "Main Cities" ? "Main Cities Off" : "Main Cities"
   })

  if ($("span", this).text == "Main Cities Off"){
    alert('map off');

              map.removeLayer(mainCitiesLayer);
  }
   if ($("span", this).text == "Main Cities"){
      alert('map on');
      map.addLayer(mainCitiesLayer);

  }

});
```

Comment: Shouldn't **$("span", this).text == "Main Cities Off")** be **$("span", this).text() == "Main Cities Off")** ?? same for the "on" one too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.text() is a function not a property

```
$("#mainCities").click(function () {
    //cache the span reference as it is used again
    var $span = $("span", this).text(function (i, text) {
        return text === "Main Cities" ? "Main Cities Off" : "Main Cities"
    })

    //.text() is a function invoke it to get the value of text
    if ($span.text() == "Main Cities Off") {
        alert('map off');
        map.removeLayer(mainCitiesLayer);
    //since there are only 2 states there is no need to use another if condition
    } else {
        alert('map on');
        map.addLayer(mainCitiesLayer);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sjwmU/)

Comment: thank you arun! That was exactly what I needed. I didn't realize that about text. Again thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`.text` is a method:

```
var method = $("span", this).text(function(i, currentText) {
   return currentText === "Main Cities"  
                        ? "Main Cities Off" 
                        : "Main Cities"; 
}).text() === 'Main Cities' ? 'addLayer' : 'removeLayer';

map[method](mainCitiesLayer);
```